# SQL Server on ssd seems slow

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssd

We recently moved SQL Server to SSD and the performance gain is not that great.

SQLIO shows enormous gains (15-100 times faster), getting sequential read/write speed up to 6GB/s.

But when we do a simple query:

```
select * 
into table2  
from table1
```

it gets roughly like 60MB/s. 2GB table takes 30 seconds to finish.

Is this normal? What speed is considered average for SSD for such a simple query?
Don't believe it's a RAM issue, 50GB of RAM..?

Comment: What client tool do you use? If the client (like SSMS) have to "render" the data, that is a very good result to do that in 30 seconds but have nothing to do with the IO.

Comment: Are the data files of that database moved to the SSD?

Comment: SSMS. What do you mean render? I believe this is read and write operation to the data file.

Comment: VM is all on SSD

Comment: @g.pickardou: `SELECT INTO` does not give any results. You're confusing it with a raw `SELECT`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Your are right I overlooked the INTO

Comment: Is you're whole environment on a single disk? or have you separated out your data files, log files, and tempdb? What are your autogrowth settings for the database that you are inserting into? are you using instant file initialisation? Which version of SQL Server are you using? How big is your database? This will dictate if 50GB is enough RAM (possibly not). Also, why do you think 30s for 2GB is slow? do you have a previous baseline to compare? Is the table being inserted in to clustered? There is a lot to consider here...

Comment: Maybe someone who has a well configured sql server on ssd drives can dublicate a 2GB table and perform such a simple operation, preferably on sql server 2008 compatibility mode?

Comment: C drive - Windows System files; D drive - data, log, tempdb files. I made a separate database wtih enough space (10GB) so no data or log files would need to grow. Not using IFI, but since files are not growing, don't see a problem. using sql server 2014

Comment: When storage is operating in GB/s, I can't understand why sql server operates in less than 100MB/s

Comment: @Atomix you didn't provide any relevant data - what is the *target* schema? Indexes? Where is the *log*? Where is tempdb? If the data, log and tempdb are all on the same disk you'll get slow performance. Your statement requires a *lot* of logging too

Comment: @Atomix what do you mean "no data or log files would need to grow"? You're inserting data, where do you think this will go? Your log file will get written to, whichever recovery model you are in

Comment: @Atomix furthermore typical SSDs reach 500MB/s ,not GB/s, unless you use a RAID array. The numbers you mention are for point reads only. Your query on the other hand reads *everything* and writes it back. If everything is stored on the same disk, that 500MB has to handle the log, the data read operation, the data *write* operation, possible spill-out to tempdb.

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos , I did. no indexes, just a simple heap.  it's all on one database.

Comment: @Atomix and btw since you try to move everything at once, everything in those two tables will be locked. Use SSIS instead to tranfer the data as a stream of rows

Comment: @Atomix heaps aren't just or simple. They affect performance. And I didn't ask where the database is. I asked where the *log* files, data files and tempdb are. Production servers never put these on the same disk or even RAID array. Otherwise a *very* rough and unrealistic estimate would tell you that you are reading at 60MB/s, writing at 60MB/s to the transaction log, another 60MB/s to the destination table for 180MB/s. Does your execution plan show any spooling? That's another 120MB/s to write and read from tempdb. That's 400MB/s

Comment: log initial size is big enough so it does not grow. It is in the cloud, so yeah it must be RAID, so we do get GB/s in sequential. SQLIO proves that.

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos no need to separate on ssd though.. many blog posts out there...

Comment: @Atomix my bag is big enough. Does it mean I don't put anything in there? *Writing* to the log is IO. Increasing the log is more IO. And SLQIO proves nothing - where is the execution plan? What does it show? Do you have any spooling? And WHY do you use a `select into` at all? You have to *allocate the target table*

Comment: @Atomix that say you do have to do so, and explain quite well that this is a big issue. If you think you don't, you misunderstood them. Consumer SSDs aren't all that faster than SAS disks or RAID arrays after all. You are using the same limited bandwidth. And, btw allocating the target table at 5MB or whatever the default for the filegroup is

Comment: Anyone else has ideas where the problem might be?

Comment: @p.Kanavos - SELECT INTO is optimal for SQL 2014 if you want to leverage parallel inserts into a heap, then add any required indexes built with a high MAXDOP.  SQL 2016 loosens that restriction a tad.  Also, SELECT INTO is a bulk logged operation which will have minimal impact on the transaction log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, there were IO limits on that VM.

As for SQLIO, it was lieing on hyper-v:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b8e1674d-f1c7-4e46-b1f1-09fb0d75d82e/strange-blazingfast-io-performance-inside-hyperv-vm?forum=winserverhyperv

https://serverfault.com/questions/287311/does-sqlio-lie-when-run-from-a-hyper-v-guest-on-a-vhd

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your SQL Server version, there are various things that can impact the performance of your query.

1. SQL Server Version:  SQL server 2014 allows parallel inserts into heap tables if you use the TABLOCK hint (SELECT INTO only).  SQL Server 2016 expands this to allow parallel inserts into heaps or clustered columnstore indexes with INSERT SELECT
2. SQL Server Edition:  Enterprise edition will issue more outstanding IO's for read-aheads than standard edition.
3. Fragmentation : Even though SSD's have no seek latency, they still do perform best with large sequential reads.  High levels of fragemention will hinder the effectiveness of read-ahead reads.
4. Fill Factor:  Rebuild an index with a fill factor of 5% and it will be 20x larger on disk, hence 20x more IO to read it.  A freshly rebuilt index will be optimal from both a fragmentation and read-ahead perspective.

Wait statistics analysis can tell you what your current bottleneck is.  If you are seeing PAGEIOLATCH_S, then reading is the issue.  Rebuild the clustered index on the source table.  If you aren't seeing an IO bottleneck, then I would assume that you are CPU bound.  Look for 1 CPU to be at 100% (if your query is running single threaded).  Solution there is to add the TABLOCK hint to try to get some parallelism.

SELECT INTO is a bulk logged operation, and won't be using TEMPDB, so no need to look into file placement for the log files or tempdb.

Comment: 1;4; I tried setting 2014 compatibily mode, added with tablock, and created clustered index with no fill factor. Now I get like ~100MB/s. Improvement.
2; Yeah we are using Standard, so that may be
3; are you talking about windows hard drives fragmentation or a cloud vendor is doing someking of fragmentation? I heard you cannot fragment ssd drives in windows...
Tried looking at wait stats using brent ozars sp_blitzfirst tool. Finding PAGEIOLATCH_S but those wait times does not seem big, gonna investigate more.

Comment: Adding wait stats results when running the query: https://imgur.com/OyIXXXQ and execution plan: https://imgur.com/BwdL4L7 .Can you see something bad?

Comment: I was referring to index fragmentation.  ALTER INDEX all ON table1 REBUILD.

Comment: Wait stats look good. query plan looks good.  How many CPU's?    if you SET STATISTICS IO ON; SET STATISTICS TIME ON, what does that show?

Comment: 4 CPU. https://imgur.com/rjrgBET